# I can't do a request that needs to set a header with axios

Tags: javascript, api, http-headers, axios

I'm trying to get some datas from an external API (from Mashape) that requires a specific header to set the API key.

Everything is ok using jQuery :

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cardbacks',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { console.dir((data.source)); },
    error: function(err) { alert(err); },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "MY_API_KEY");
    }
});
```

However, when I'm trying to do the same request with axios for a react application, I have a 404 error:

```js
axios.get({
  url: 'https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cardbacks',
  headers: {
      "X-Mashape-Authorization": "MY_API_KEY"
   }
 })
```

Is there something I'm missing ? Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Could you tell the exact 404 error text? does it come at GET or at OPTIONS request?(you can check it in Network panel in Chrome devtools)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try also to do it like this without setting defaults:

```
axios.get('https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cardbacks', {
      headers: { "X-Mashape-Key": "MY_API_KEY" }
    })
      .then((resp) => {
        console.dir(resp);

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

It should work.

PS I also observed that you use different header keys in question(X-Mashape-Authorization) and answer(X-Mashape-Key). Maybe that is also somehow related to 404 error?

Comment: I finally found it more easy with the config since all my calls are made towards the same API, but you answered to my initial question, so you have my upvote :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is better to set default values to similar calls. And thank you for upvoting. Good luck!

Comment: does this apply to post method also? i can't get it working. it seems to send headers as a payload property instead

Comment: @razorxan yes, it should work. don't forget to change it to axios.put though :) Check official documentation on ho to use params and change config https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios. If you can provide details on your exact case then I may help more.

Answer (score 14):

I finally understood.

We need to set the header BEFORE the request using `axios.defaults.headers.common['header_name'] = "API_KEY";` :

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com';
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Mashape-Key'] = "API_KEY";
axios.get('/cardbacks')
    .then((resp) => {
        console.dir(resp);
    });
```

Comment: It's a good idea to save the copy of the previous defaults and reset the defaults again, because the above will affect **all** subsequent requests.

Answer (score 4):

I got better way to solve this .

You just need add parameters format from axios like this below:

```js
axios({
    method: <method>,
    url: <url>,
    data: <params>,
    headers: { common: <headers> },
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!cb) return { error: 'No callback' };
    return cb(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => cb(err.response));
```