# Use Axios.Get with params and config together

Tags: javascript, axios

How do I use `axios.get` with params and config together? My code is not working. Please help me this basic issue!

```
let config = {
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this.$store.state.token}
}
let f = 0

axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/f/', {
    params: {
        page: f + 1
    },
    config: this.config
})
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Axios takes the entire config in the second argument, not a list of config objects. Put the params inside the config, and pass the entire object as the second argument:

```js
let f = 0

let config = {
  headers: {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this.$store.state.token},
  params: {
    page: f + 1
  },
}

axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/f/', config)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass a custom header you can do so by

```
var config = {
    'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this.$store.state.token
}
let f = 0

axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/f/', {
    params: {
        page: f + 1
    },
    headers: config
})
```

Please follow the documentation to so see any further requirements, or you can comment here too.

Try this out too:

```
var config = {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this.$store.state.token}
};

axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/f/',{
    params: {
        page: f + 1
    }}, config);
```

Documention:

1. http://codeheaven.io/how-to-use-axios-as-your-http-client/
2. [I can't do a request that needs to set a header with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123079/i-cant-do-a-request-that-needs-to-set-a-header-with-axios)
3. https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: headers and params should be siblings in the config object.
This:
axios.get('http://localhost', { params: {page: 1}, headers: config })
Not this:
axios.get('http://localhost', { params: {page: 1}},config);

Comment: as stated by @getsetbro, params and headers should be SIBLINGS. Thanks getsetbro