# Rails API empty request headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, request

Sending request from javascript to rails and providing the `Authorization` header with a token always shows up as empty headers on my rails API.

I have the follow piece of base code for all my API controllers:

```
module Api
 class BaseController < ActionController::API
  before_action :require_login

  private

  def require_login
   unless signed_in?
    head :unauthorized
   end
  end

  def signed_in?
    current_user.present?
  end

  def current_user
    if request.headers['Authorization'].present?
      User.find_by(token: request.headers['Authorization'])
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

end

Doing my fetch request on javascript side like this:

```
  fetch(`/api/clients?page=${page}`, {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Authorization': AUTH_TOKEN
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  })
```

Fetching the value `Authorization` from `request.headers` always comes up as nil.

Anyone knows what might be going wrong?

Comment: what do you see if `puts request.headers` ?

Comment: I think it will be `request.headers['HTTP_Authorization']`.

Comment: I'm unable to puts request.headers. And HTTP_Authorization doesn't work either

Comment: Why you are not able btw? Add it to the first line of the method `current_user`?

Comment: Because `request.headers` does not respond to puts.

Comment: `puts` works all over the Ruby.. Not sure what you meant. You need to check the output to the log file.. Are you checking there?

Comment: FYI, check how to use [custom headers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Headers.html) if the current one you can't figure out.. I have to go now to sleep :)

Comment: Is there a typo? Could you confirm that. `class BaseController < ActionController::AP`

Comment: can you try `request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`, also like @BerkhanBerkdemir has asked if it's a typo make sure you change `class BaseController < ActionController::AP` to `class BaseController < ActionController::API`

Comment: The typo was just a bad copy paste on my end. I'm really using `ActionController::API`. `request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` returns `nil`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the [`Fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) library, you can use the [`new Request()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) object which helps you customize your configurations.

```javascript
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request

var myHeaders = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'Authorization': AUTH_TOKEN
});

var myInit = { method: 'GET',
               headers: myHeaders,
               mode: 'cors',
               cache: 'default' };

var myRequest = new Request(`/api/clients?page=${page}, myInit);

fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
  ...
});
```

I had the same issue with `Axios` and it turns out I was using a `get` request with headers and params ***wrongly***.

```javascript
const params = { id: "ghjfsd7634" };

const headers = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: token,
    },
};


 axios
      .get(url, params, headers)
      .then(function foo(response) {
          handleResponse(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function foo(error) {
          console.log("GET Resource Error");
          console.log(error);
      });
```

***Correct way:*** Params and headers in `get` requests are passed differently compared to `post`, `put` etc. requests. [Axios takes the entire config in the second argument, not a list of config objects. Put the params inside the config, and pass the entire object as the second argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48261393/8050183):

```javascript
 const params = { id: "ghjfsd7634" };
 const headers = {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     Authorization: token,
 };

 const config = { headers, params };

 await axios
     .get(url, config)
     .then(function foo(response) {
         handleResponse(response.data);
     })
     .catch(function foo(error) {
         console.log("GET Resource Error");
         console.log(error);
     });
```