# Not able to make api call using axios instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, backend, trello

```
export class TrelloService {
    public instance: AxiosInstance;
    constructor(token: string) {
        this.instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: `https://api.trello.com/1?key=${process.env.TRELLO_API_KEY}&token=${token}`,
        });
    }

    public async getUserDetails(email: string): Promise<any> {
        const userDetails = await this.instance.get(`/members/${email}`);
        return userDetails;
    }
    
    public static async getUserDetails2(
        email: string,
        token: string,
        throwError = false,
    ): Promise<any> {
        let userDetails: any = null;

        const userDetails = await axios.get(`https://api.trello.com/1/members/${email}key=${process.env.TRELLO_API_KEY}&token=${token}`)
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

If i am invoking getUserDetails by creating an object of class TrelloService, its not working. Trello it throwing me an error with status code 404. But if I directly invoke getUserDetails2 method it is working fine.
This is the object creation part

```
    const trelloService = new TrelloService(accessToken);
    const temp = await trelloService.getUserDetails(email);
```

I tried manipulating axios instance but it didn't work out for me. Is it because url is getting attach at the end, even after query variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is because axios merge the strings together

You have to use the params option

Change this line

```js
this.instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://api.trello.com/1?key=${process.env.TRELLO_API_KEY}&token=${token}`,
});
```

to

```js
this.instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://api.trello.com/1`,
  params: {
    key: process.env.TRELLO_API_KEY,
    token: token,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are trying to get an invalid url:

```bash
# invalid:
https://api.trello.com/1?key=key&token=token/members/john@doe.io

# valid:
https://api.trello.com/1/members/john@doe.io?key=key&token=token
```

Try to add params on every requests:

```js
export class TrelloService {
  public instance: AxiosInstance;
  public baseParams: { key: string; token: string };

  constructor(token: string) {
    this.instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: `https://api.trello.com/1`,
    });
    this.baseParams = {
      key: process.env.TRELLO_API_KEY,
      token,
    };
  }

  public async getUserDetails(email: string): Promise<any> {
    const userDetails = await this.instance.get(`/members/${email}`, {
      params: { otherParam: "1", ...this.baseParams },
    });
    return userDetails;
  }
}
```

You can also use [`interceptor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789480/11692562) to add params to every requests