# ReactJS : Axios get request with header and data leads to bad request 400

Tags: reactjs, spring, get, axios

I have a Spring application running on localhost which has an endpoint. This is a get api and  requires an authorization header with bearer carrying the jwt and the username to get some data.

When i try to hit this endpoint using postman, it works fine.

But using axios, i get a 400 bad request.

Here is how i make the request.

```
const jwt = "jwt";
const api = "http://localhost:7000/api";
const response = await axios.get(api, {
    params: { username: username },
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
```

I referred the first answer available on the link below to come up with this method.

[Use Axios.Get with params and config together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261227/use-axios-get-with-params-and-config-together)

My spring application supports CrossOrigin requests for now so that should not be a problem.

The same request works fine without **params / data** in the config.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try {"...api?username="+username} ? Also, try this config: {withCredentials: true} .

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the code you shared the `kwt` token is actually a string with the value `jwt`, I'm not sure if this is the token used for you API but it seems it's not, since you're getting the `400`, I'd advise you to update the logic for getting the correct token if this is not the one.

```js
const jwt = "jwt" //replace with correct token;
```