# Token is correct in frontend, but in the backend it's undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, authorization, mern

In the React front end I want to fetch transactions associated with the logged in user, whose token is stored in the `userInfo` property of `userLogin` state variable in Redux. So in the action creator function associated with fetching transactions I have the following

```
const token = `Bearer ${getState().userLogin.userInfo.token}`;

console.log(token);

const config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: token,
  },
};

const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/transactions', {}, config);
```

The `console.log(toke)` outputs the token correctly.

In the backend, however, when I check `req.headers.authorization`, I get `undefined`, and my request to fetch data is denied with an authorization error. Why `req.headers.authorization=undefined` in the backend, although I send it from the frontend in the headers?

Comment: What type of backend do you have? A custom Node.js backend? Are you using Create React App to forward `/api` requests to your backend?

Comment: My backend is custom and built using node.js/express.js and the database solution is mongoDB. Yes, I used create-react-app to create my React frontend, and I set the `proxy` property in `package.json` to be the server url and port.

Comment: Alright, that's frustrating. Does it behave differently if you write `axios({ method: 'get', url: '/api/v1/transactions', headers: { Authorization: token } });` as a test? Doesn't seem like the `axios.get` method has an argument for sending data, just the `url` and the `config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing config params in wrong order, should be

```
axios.get('/api/v1/transactions', config);
```

See this for more details: [Use Axios.Get with params and config together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261227/use-axios-get-with-params-and-config-together)